# TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ReactDOM is undefined ERROR en index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

He creado un proyecto de **react nuevo**. He copiado el index.js del proyecto antiguo, ya que tiene que ser igual. Pero en este me da un error de **keycloak,** he mirado el package.json y he visto que la version de **react-dom** no es la misma, el nuevo es la version 18, el proyecto anterior el 17. El resto todo igual. Mi index jss es el siguiente.

***Importaciones:***

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import React from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import App from './App'; 
import './index.css'; 
import global_en from './translation/en/global.json';        
import global_es from './translation/es/global.json'; 
import global_gl from './translation/gl/global.json';    
import global_pt from './translation/pt/global.json';
```

***Codigo:***

```
const txtnav=(window.navigator.language).substring(0,2) != null? (window.navigator.language).substring(0,2) : 'es'
console.log(txtnav)
let idioma = localStorage.getItem('idioma')
i18next.init({
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
    lng:  idioma != null ? idioma : txtnav,
    resources: {
        es: {
            global: global_es,
        },
        pt: {
            global: global_pt,
        }, 
        gl: {
            global: global_gl,
        },
        en: {
            global: global_en,
        }         
    },
})


const renderApp = () => ReactDOM.render(

    < I18nextProvider i18n={i18next}>
        <App />
    </I18nextProvider>,
    
    document.getElementById('root'));

UserService.initKeycloak(renderApp);
```

En el proyecto anterior funciona sin problema.
En este el error es:

***TypeError: react_dom_client__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.render is not a function***

he probado a incluir dentro  <React.StrictMode>, pero tampoco me funciona

Comment: A ver tus importaciones en la parte de arriba.

Comment: import i18next from 'i18next';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import global_en from './translation/en/global.json';
import global_es from './translation/es/global.json';
import global_gl from './translation/gl/global.json';
import global_pt from './translation/pt/global.json';

Comment: Basicamente lo que dices es que quisiste utilizar lo que estaba en un proyecto de react V18 en uno de V17? Te recomendaria que desisntales ambas versiones de los paquetes de la v17 `npm uninstall react react-dom` e instales la version correspondiente `npm install react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2`. Confirma si es esto lo que estas tratando de hacer!